# If the bisector of an angle of a triangle also bisects the opposite side, prove that the triangle is isosceles.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> If the bisector of an angle of a triangle also bisects the opposite side, prove that the triangle is isosceles.

Here is my solution...

[image]

To Prove - Triangle ABC is isosceles or AB = AC.

1. $BD = CD$ (Given)
2. $\angle BAD = \angle CAD$ (Given)
3. $\angle ABD = \angle ACD$ ($AD$ is a common side, angles opposite equal sides are equal)
4. $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$ are congruent as per AAS postulate.
5. And therefore, $AB = AC$.

Is this a right answer or am I wrong somewhere ? I've seen solutions for this question but all of them have solved through constructions. I feel this is a shorter and logical way. Am I right or wrong in this approach ?

Comment: *"Angles opposite equal sides are equal"* (aka, the Isosceles Triangle Theorem) applies when the angles and sides are parts of a single triangle. You've applied this to angles and sides in different triangles ($\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$). ... To see the flaw another way, redraw your image so that $\overline{BC}$ is *slanted* instead of horizontal.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you for clearing my confusion.

Comment: Fun fact: It is in general true that the ratio of the two parts of the opposite side ($BD/CD$) is equal to the ratio of the two adjacent sides ($AB/AC$). In this case, the ratio happens to be 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong because you did not prove that $\Delta ABD\cong\Delta ACD.$

The hint:

Let $E$ be placed on the line $AD$ such that $D$ is a mid-point of $AE$.

Thus, $$\Delta ADC\cong\Delta EDB,$$ $$\measuredangle BAD=\measuredangle BED.$$
Can you take it from this?

Comment: Yes, I can prove it from here, thank you !

Comment: @Bhashwar Sengupta You are welcome!