# If the median and bisector of one of its sides of a triangle coincide, then the height also coincides and the triangle is isosceles.

Tags: geometry

If the median and bisector of one of its sides of a triangle coincide, then the height also coincides and the triangle is isosceles.

So, to see that is isosceles I used the idea of this question: [If the bisector of an angle of a triangle also bisects the opposite side, prove that the triangle is isosceles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336688/if-the-bisector-of-an-angle-of-a-triangle-also-bisects-the-opposite-side-prove)

Now, to see that the height also coincides, I tried to assume that it doesn't but I don't see any contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two triangles made by the median are congruent and the base is a straight line so each angle made by the base and the median is $180/2 =90$ which makes the median to be the height as well.

Comment: why? theres literally no reason to assume that

Comment: Please check the link provided by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Call the triangle $\triangle ABC$ and let $AD$ be such that $\angle BAD=\angle CAD$ and $\overline{BD}=\overline{CD}$.

By SSA triangle congruence for non-obtuse triangles, $\triangle BAD\cong\triangle CAD$. So, $\angle BDA=\angle CDA$, and $\angle BDA+\angle CDA=180^\circ$, so they are both right angles. Since $\angle DBA=\angle DCA$, the triangle is isosceles.