# Prove that if an angle bisector and median of a vertex and opposite side are same, the triangle is an isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

My incomplete solution is:

Given: In $\triangle ABC$, $\overline{AD}$ is both angle bisector of angle $\angle A$ and median to side $\overline{BC}$, therefore, $\angle BAD = \angle CAD$ and $\overline{BD} = \overline{CD}$.

Proof:

[image]

Comparing $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$,

$\angle BAD = \angle CAD$ (Given)

$\overline{BD} = \overline{CD}$ (Given)

$\overline{AD} = \overline{AD}$ (Common side)

This is not sufficient to prove the congruency of the two triangles. What am I missing?

Note: An incomplete(?) proof is given on [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336688/if-the-bisector-of-an-angle-of-a-triangle-also-bisects-the-opposite-side-prove). Since I do not have 50+ reputation, I cannot comment on that question.

Comment: The linked proof looks fine. Why don't you like it?

Comment: Why didn’t you use the angle bisector theorem? According to the angle bisector theorem, an angle bisector of an angle of a triangle divides the opposite side into two parts that are proportional to other sides of the triangle. In other words, $\dfrac{BD}{DC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}$. Since $\dfrac{BD}{DC} = 1$, we have $\dfrac{AB}{AC}=1$, i.e.,  $AB=AC$.

Comment: Notice that the two triangles ADC and ADB have the same air then :
$$\dfrac{1}{2} AC \times AD \sin \angle DAC = \dfrac{1}{2} AB \times AD \sin \angle DAB$$

Comment: @YNK I did not know about angle-bisector theorem. Thank you so much for your reply. Now, $\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}$, SAS theorem can be applied to prove the congruence of the two triangles.

Comment: @Essaidi Thank you so much for your reply. I have never seen use of area-equivalence to derive such a result. I really like your approach.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: In $\triangle ABC$, $\overline{AD}$ is both angle bisector of angle $\angle A$ and median to side $\overline{BC}$, therefore, $\angle BAD = \angle CAD$ and $\overline{BD} = \overline{CD}$.

Proof:

[image]

Comparing $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$,

According to the angle bisector theorem, an angle bisector of an angle of a triangle divides the opposite side into two parts that are proportional to other sides of the triangle. In other words, $\dfrac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{CD}} = \dfrac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{AC}}$. Since $\dfrac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{CD}} = 1$, we have $\dfrac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{AC}} = 1$, i.e., $\overline{AB} = \overline{AC}$.

$\angle BAD = \angle CAD$ (Given)

$\overline{AD} = \overline{AD}$ (Common side)

Using Side-Angle-Side theorem, it is proved that $\triangle ABC = \triangle ACD$.

Since the two triangles are congruent, their corresponding sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ must be equal, which implies that the $\triangle ABC$ must be an isosceles triangle.

Thanks to @YNK and @Essaidi for their valuable inputs.